# Postgres CDC similar to MS SQL Server's sys.sp_cdc_enable_db

Tags: postgresql, cdc, logical-replication

I am looking for a change data capture solution for Postgres that is similar to  sys.sp_cdc_enable_db
in MSSQL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

We want to be able to produce a CDC table where each row represents the values in one of the source table's columns at over time (for all or most columns).

There are trigger based audit systems, but these are fragile. Solutions like Debezium seem like massive overkill for the scope of my problem (one server, several databases, many tables, a few GB of updates per week).

It seems like it ought to be fairly straightforward to use logical replication and consume WAL messages into a table within the same database, but I cannot find anything that does it.

The pg_recvlogical command with wal2json looks like it could work, or maybe something like this:
https://idrawone.github.io/2020/04/17/Replicate-multiple-PostgreSQL-servers-to-a-single-MongoDB-server-using-logical-decoding-output-plugin/
but I just want send change data back into same database into a history table rather than a separate Mongo server.

Does anyone know of a solution which does this?

Thanks!

Eric

Comment: there is no equivalent of MS SQL Server CDC in PostGreSQL. All similar bjets (like Kafka) uses triggers while MS reads directly the log file... See differences between MS SQL and PG at : http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/